# AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'

Tags: python, numpy

Strange behavior in PyCharm (2021.2.1 Professional Edition) with Python 3.9 and numpy 1.21.2.
When I run my program with "Run" then it works as expected. But when I run it with "Debug" then the following error messages appears and the program stops:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\JobAnalyzer\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    core.numerictypes.typeDict,
AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'
python-BaseException
```

Any hints what could be the cause?

It crashes immediately at the following line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And in numpy at this line:

```
    # Numpy 1.20.0, 2020-10-19
    __deprecated_attrs__["typeDict"] = (
        core.numerictypes.typeDict,   <--- CRASH HERE
        "`np.typeDict` is a deprecated alias for `np.sctypeDict`."
    )
```

Comment: Do you know what's different when you run "Debug" (I don't, which is why I'm asking).  Is it importing numpy from the same virtualenv?  It sounds like you might have a broken numpy installation, or might be mixing multiple numpy versions from different environments.

Comment: PyCharm uses the same virtual environment even if I press Run or Debug button.

Comment: I've tried it now with Python 3.8 and 3.9 without virtual environment and the problem disappeared. It seems to have to do with the virtual environment.

Comment: Chances are you had multiple Numpy installs on your PYTHONPATH and one was interfering with the one in the virtualenv.  This happens to me sometimes.

Comment: How did you run it without a virtual environment? I'm having the same issue, where I can't run debug mode.

Comment: I've used a virtual environment. Without virtual environment ist works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bug is documented [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50959), it is related to PySide2, which is used by default by PyCharm for PyQt compatibility. The workaround (besides downgrading numpy) is to go to PyCharm's settings / "Build, Execution, Deployment" / "Python debugger", and there uncheck or change the value of the PyQt compatibility drop-down to something else than *Auto* or *PySide2*:

[image]